# Transforming relational data bases to graph databases

Tags: postgresql, graph, neo4j, etl

As part of my final thesis, I must **transform a relational database in a graph-oriented database**, specifically a PostgreSQL database into a Neo4j embedded database. Now, the way is the problem. In Rik Van Bruggen's book: Learning Neo4j, he mentions a data import process using ETL activities with Trascend and MuleSoft tools, but in their official sites, there's no documentation about how to do it, neither help documentation nor examples. Apart from these tools, what other ways can I use to transform this information without using my own code?

Comment: CSV importing? Have you had a look to this? http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/

Comment: https://github.com/nuko-yokohama/neo4j_fdw

Comment: Are you asking about how to get relational data into a graph?   Or are you asking about how to get a relational MODEL into a graph MODEL?

Comment: Did you actually check his site: http://blog.bruggen.com he has examples for both. Also check out the musicbrainz blog post http://neo4j.com/blog/musicbrainz-in-neo4j-part-1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some modeling advice:

A well normalized relational model, which was not yet denormalized for performance reasons can be translated into the equivalent graph model.
Graph model shapes are mostly driven by use-cases, so there will be opportunity for optimization and model evolution afterwards.

A good, normalized Entity-Relationship diagram often already represents a decent graph model. 
So if you still have the orignal ER diagram available, try to use it as a guide.

Here are some tips that help you with the transformation:

- Each entity table is represented by a label on nodes
- Each row in a table is a node
- Columns on those tables become node properties.
- Remove technical primary keys, keep business primary keys
- Add unique constraints for business primary keys, add indexes for frequent lookup attributes
- Replace foreign keys with relationships to the other table, remove them afterwards
- Remove data with default values, no need to store those
- Data in tables that is denormalized and duplicated might have to be pulled out into separate nodes to get a cleaner model.
- Indexed column names, might indicate an array property (like email1, email2, email3)
- JOIN tables are transformed into relationships, columns on those tables become relationship properties

It is important to have an understanding of the graph model before you start to import data, then it just becomes the task of hydrating that model.

Comment: Michael, thanks again. I've taken your advice. As solution to my problem, I created a ETL process that transforms the required data from relational model into oriented-graph database. The task was difficult, also when the data isn't distributed how one can expect. In my database source, a table doesn't represent an entity, all required concepts (nodes and relationships) are unorganized, so this complicates the transformation process.

Answer (score 4):

`LOAD CSV` might be your best option, but of course it means outputting a CSV first.  Here are some great resources:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html

http://watch.neo4j.org/video/112447027

http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/

http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/load-cvs-with-success/

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

I've also written a ruby gem which lets you write a little ruby code to import data from various sources.  It's called [neo4apis](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis).  You can look at the neo4apis-twitter gem to get an idea for how it works:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis-twitter/

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis-twitter/blob/master/lib/neo4apis/twitter.rb

I've actually been wanting to implement a neo4apis-activerecord to make it easy to import from SQL with ActiveRecord

Comment: Well, I have tried to do this, but the source datasets aren't in a same table, they are disordered in many tables at the database. Really, I have tried all with LOAD CSV. Thanks for the answer, really unexpected (My first question in this site) In this past time, I have found a solution: creating a ETL process in a java application, which uses postgres driver and neo4j embedded libraries, working at all!

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly export data from relational and import to neo4j.

Because these are two different database structures.

**Relational Database** -
A relational database is a set of tables containing data fitted into predefined categories. Each table (which is sometimes called a relation) contains one or more data categories in columns. Each row contains a unique instance of data for the categories defined by the columns.

**Graph-oriented database** -

A graph database is essentially a collection of nodes and edges. Each node represents an entity (such as a person or business) and each edge represents a connection or relationship between two nodes.

**Sollution To your Problem**-

First, you need to design Neo4j Data structure. e.g What will be the nodes you required, what will be the relationships between the nodes.

After that you create Script in your application language to fetch data from relational database and insert it into neo4j.

**Load CSA** is a option to Import/Export (backup) functionality with graph database. you can not directly Export/Import data from **Relational DB** to **Graph DB**